# NerdTree... after using <m> bottom panel stays bigger and wont disappear

Tags: vimrc, neovim, plugin-nerdtree

When using  Menu in NERDTree to create a directory/file and toggle it off, will keep bottom window open.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Vim :-). I'm afraid the resolution of your screencast is too small to be able to follow what you are doing. Would it be possible to provide another screencast (maybe you could reduce the size of your console to help to focus?).

Comment: Thx @VivianDeSmedt!!. Pretty much I hit <F2> to toggle NERDTree, then <m> to popup the menu to create a directory and after toggle it off again..the bottom panel that appears to write a <cmd> still open.

Comment: In my version of NERDTree (m) is to move a file or folder and (a) to add a file or folder. The menu subwindows get closed after the action is performed. Do you use the last version of NerdTree?

Comment: This may well be better suited as a question to the plugin maintainers

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by an incompatibility between NERDTree and Vim 9.0.

You can fix it by applying [this hotfix](https://github.com/preservim/nerdtree/pull/1322/files) to your local copy of NERDTree.

Some alternatives:

- Add `let g:NERDTreeMinimalMenu=1` to your `.vimrc` to set menu to display in a single line
- Use a version of Vim earlier than the 9.0 release

See [issue #1321](https://github.com/preservim/nerdtree/issues/1321) in the NERDTree repo for more info.